# Is it bad practice or plainfully wrong to declare a class which has methods that returns some value from another class in Python?

Tags: python, class, design-patterns

I wanted to separate the logic for my code and I don't have any experience with design patterns, but this question is nogging my head. I have a class *Person* that should have a pair of keys for encrypting and decrypting messages. The class calls methods from another class *RSA*, which contains all the logic for handling this.

Here is a snippet of the code for Person:

```
from RSA import RSA 

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._keys = None

    def generate_keys(self):
        self._keys = RSA.generate_keys()

    def sign(self, message):
        return RSA.sign(message, self._keys)

    def verify(self, recipent_pk, signature, message):
        return RSA.verify(recipent_pk, signature, message)
```

And a snippet for RSA:

```
class RSA:

    def generate_keys():
        private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
            public_exponent=65537,
            key_size=2048,
            backend=default_backend()
        )
        return private_key

    def sign(message: int, private_key: rsa.RSAPrivateKey):
        bytes_msg = message_to_bytes(message)
        signature = private_key.sign(
            bytes_msg,
            padding.PSS(
                mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
                salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
            ),
            hashes.SHA256()
        )
        return signature
```

I'm asking because Pylint is yelling at me for not declaring self as the first parameter for each method in RSA. However, the code works fine without declaring it, but am I missing something here? Furthermore, *message_to_bytes* is a helper function used to convert the input from an integer to byte representation. Is it okay that it goes outside the class at the module level, or do I need to declare it inside the RSA class? (Currently it works, but it feels wrong coming from Java).

Comment: Methods that don't take `self` or `cls` as the first parameter should be declared `@staticmethod`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the return types.

Comment: Why is `RSA` a class? It seems like it should just be a module with top-level functions.

Comment: Unlike in Java, you don't have to shoe-horn everything into a class just because the language requires exactly one class per file.

Comment: I recently learned about decoupling. Shouldn't the Person class be given an instance of the RSA class, for example through the constructor? This question is just for my knowledge.

Comment: @yosemite You should post an actual question, rather than asking in the comments of another question.